# I can't get hover or mouseenter to unbind and rebind again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried sooooo many different methods of this that others have suggested, but I don't understand what i'm doing wrong and really need some help. I have tried using various combinations of hover, mouseenter/mouseleave, on/off, bind/unbind.

Basically, I can get things to unbind, but I can't get them to bind again afterwards.

I put together a jsfiddle with a basic example. If you click the "Hover Off" button, mouseenter is disabled like intended. But then if you click the "Hover On" button after, mouseenter does not enable again.

http://jsfiddle.net/770b5p8q/3/

Here is "hover" functionality:

```
$('.square').each(function(){
    $(this).bind("mouseenter", function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
    $(this).bind("mouseleave", function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Here is what should enable/disable it:

```
$('.hover_enabled').click(function(){
    $('.square').each(function(){
        $(this).bind("mouseenter");
        $(this).bind("mouseleave");
    });
});

$('.hover_disabled').click(function(){
    $('.square').each(function(){
        $(this).unbind("mouseenter");
        $(this).unbind("mouseleave");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you rebind it back you need to pass function as well.

```
$('.hover_enabled').click(function(){
    $('.square').each(function(){
        $(this).bind("mouseenter", function(){
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
        $(this).bind("mouseleave", function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the function for binding and unbinding the handlers, something like:

```
var mouseEnterHandler = function () {
    $(this).addClass('active');
}
var mouseLeaveHandler = function () {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
};

$('.square').bind("mouseenter", mouseEnterHandler)
            .bind("mouseleave", mouseLeaveHandler);

$('.hover_enabled').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.hover_disabled').removeClass('active');

    // I need to bind hover here
    $('.square').bind("mouseenter", mouseEnterHandler)
                .bind("mouseleave", mouseLeaveHandler);
});
```

But the code becomes ugly and unmaintainable. You can use event delegation instead:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.square.hoverable', function(event) {
    // toggle the class by checking the type of the event
    $(this).toggleClass('active', event.type === 'mouseenter');
});

// caching the state changers 
var $e = $('.hover_enabled, .hover_disabled').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this).addClass('active'),
        isHoverable = $this.hasClass('hover_enabled');

    // exclude the clicked element from the set and remove the class
    $e.not($this).removeClass('active');
    $('.square').toggleClass('hoverable', isHoverable);
});
```

The above `mouseenter mouseleave` handler is only executed when the `.square` element has `hoverable` className. You can also remove the event handler and use CSS for styling.

```
.square.hoverable:hover {

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bztec1f4/

Comment: Yeah it does seem like the code will get pretty crazy. I'm not sure what event delegation is though :(

Comment: Ohhh, okay I posted that comment too soon. I couldn't get the enable/disable hover to work, so I actually did something similar to that with toggling classes. It works for the most part but i'm doing something pretty complex and am encountering some bugs that would not be an issue if I could just outright disable/enable the hover.

Comment: @Shonna well, if your code is complex it means there is something wrong. You should reduce the complexity.

Comment: I just mean there is a lot going on, the site I am working on is very interactive and has lots of moving parts. So like the toggle class thing worked fine 95% of the time, but then if you do a specific order of events, things weren't fine. I'm sure someone with more skill than me could figure it out but right now completely disabling mouseenter is the best solution I could come up with.